# Affine cipher of the 3rd order

Tags: python, python-3.x

write an affine cipher of the 3rd (kth) order, admissible with the text "hello world" key. The message is divided into k-grams. Each k-gram of X is replaced by a k-gram. Each k-gram X' of the cryptotext is replaced by a k-gram D(X')=A'X'+S', where A'=A-1 and S'=–A'S is the decryption key. Below is my code, but it seems easier to create a new one, the problem arises in the decoding process, as far as I understand:

```
import numpy as np

def affine_encrypt(message, key1, key2):
    message = message.upper().replace(" ", "")

    letter_to_num = {chr(i + 65): i for i in range(26)}
    num_to_letter = {i: chr(i + 65) for i in range(26)}

    ciphertext = ""

    nums = [letter_to_num[char] for char in message]

    n = len(nums)
    m = int(np.ceil(n / 3))
    nums = np.pad(nums, (0, m * 3 - n), mode='constant')
    nums = np.reshape(nums, (m, 3))

    prod = np.dot(nums, key1)
    key2 = np.tile(key2.T, (m, 1))
    nums = np.mod(prod + key2, 26)

    for row in nums:
        for num in row:
            ciphertext += num_to_letter[num]

    return ciphertext


def affine_decrypt(ciphertext, key1, key2):
    letter_to_num = {chr(i + 65): i for i in range(26)}
    num_to_letter = {i: chr(i + 65) for i in range(26)}

    plaintext = ""

    nums = [letter_to_num[char] for char in ciphertext]

    n = len(nums)
    m = int(np.ceil(n / 3))
    nums = np.pad(nums, (0, m * 3 - n), mode='constant')
    nums = np.reshape(nums, (m, 3))

    key2 = np.tile(key2.T, (m, 1))
    try:
        nums = np.round(np.mod(np.dot(nums - key2, np.linalg.inv(key1)), 26)).astype(int)
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
        print("Error: Key 1 is not invertible!")
        return ""

    for row in nums:
        for num in row:
            plaintext += num_to_letter[num]

    plaintext = plaintext[:n]

    return plaintext

key1 = np.array([[4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 1], [3, 2, 4]])  
key2 = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])  
message = "Hello world"

ciphertext = affine_encrypt(message, key1, key2)
print("Ciphertext:", ciphertext)

plaintext = affine_decrypt(ciphertext, key1, key2)
print("Plaintext:", plaintext)
```

result is
Ciphertext: OBNVDXDWONLJ
Plaintext: DSDDQGWPBDAA

i tried using alphabet also asci